# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDC1

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I wrote the code that can generate random Geometry figures and display it in cmd in text form.

Here is my 3 files:

Geometry.h

```
#pragma once

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW


#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define PI 3.1415926535
using namespace std;

enum color { White, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Black };
enum _shape { line, rectangle, circle, picture }; //to roll shapes

void print_color(color c);

//--------------------------Point---------------------------
class Point {
private:
    int m_xc, m_yc; //(x,y) coordinats
public:
    Point(int x = 0, int y = 0) : m_xc(x), m_yc(y) {}
    int x(void) const   { return m_xc; };
    int y(void) const   { return m_yc; };
    Point operator+(const Point& p) const 
    {
        return Point(m_xc+p.m_xc, m_yc+p.m_yc);
    }
    Point& operator+=(const Point& p) //move point
    { 
        m_xc += p.m_xc; 
        m_yc += p.m_yc; 
        return *this; 
    } 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p);
    Point move(int x, int y){
        m_xc += x;
        m_yc += y;
        return *this;
    }
};

//------------------------Shape-----------------------------

class Shape  {
protected:
    Point m_org; 
    color m_color; 
    _shape m_shape;
public:
    Shape(const Point& p1 = 0, color c = White, _shape sh = line) : m_org(p1), m_color(c), m_shape(sh){};
    virtual ~Shape() = 0 {};
    virtual void move(const Point& p) = 0;
    virtual void draw(char tabs) const = 0;
    virtual void Who_am_I() const = 0;
    virtual double Area() const { return 0; };
    virtual void Save2File(ofstream &myfile) const = 0;
};
//------------------------Line---------------------------------

class Line : public Shape {
protected:
    Point m_end; // line end
public:
    Line(const Point& p1, const Point& p2, color c) : Shape(p1, c, line), m_end(p2) {}
    void move(const Point& p)
    {
        m_org += p;
        m_end += p;
    }
    void draw(char tabs) const;
    void Who_am_I() const { 
        print_color(m_color);
        cout << "Line"; 
    }
    double length() const;
    double Area() const { return 0; };
    void Save2File(ofstream &myfile) const;
};
//----------------------Rectangle-------------------------------

class Rectangle : public Shape {
protected:
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    Rectangle(const Point& p1, color c = White, int w = 0, int h = 0) : Shape(p1, c, rectangle), width(w), height(h) {}
    void move(const Point& p)
    {
        m_org += p;
    }
    void draw(char tabs) const;
    void Who_am_I() const { 
        print_color(m_color);
        cout << "Rectangle"; 
    }
    double Area() const { return width*height; };
    void Save2File(ofstream &myfile) const;
};
//----------------------Circle---------------------------

class Circle : public Shape {
protected:
    int radius;
public:
    Circle(const Point& p1, color c = White, int r = 0) : Shape(p1, c, circle), radius(r) {};
    void move(const Point& p)
    {
        m_org += p;
    }
    void draw(char tabs) const;
    void Who_am_I() const { 
        print_color(m_color);
        cout << "Circle"; 
    }
    double Area() const { return PI*(double)radius*(double)radius; };
    void Save2File(ofstream &myfile) const;
};
//--------------------------Picture-------------------------

class Picture : public Shape {
private:
    Picture(const Picture&); //CCtor is not accessible from main
protected:
    Shape** m_shapes;   //array of pointers to shapes
    int m_count;        //number of shapes
    static unsigned idx; //number of pictures created for debug
public:
    Picture(const Point& p1 = 0, color c = White) : Shape(p1, c, picture), m_count(0){ idx++; }
    ~Picture();
    void insert_shape(Shape* sh);
    void draw(char tabs) const;
    void move(const Point& p){ m_org += p; };
    void Who_am_I() const { 
        print_color(m_color);
        cout << "Picture"; 
    }
    void Save2File(ofstream &myfile) const;
    int get_count(void){ return m_count; }
    double Area() const;
    unsigned GetAmPic(void) { return idx; }
};
```

Geometry.cpp

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW

#include "geometry.h"
using namespace std;

unsigned Picture::idx = 0;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    os << '(' << p.x() << ',' << p.y() << ')';
    return os;
}

void print_color(color c) {
    string color_print[6] = { "White ", "Red ", "Green ", "Blue ", "Yellow ", "Black " };
    cout << color_print[(int)c];
}

//------------------Line methods--------------------
void Line::draw(char tabs) const
{
    cout << string(tabs, '\t');
    Who_am_I();
    cout << " from " << m_org << " to " << m_end << endl;
}

double Line::length() const
{
    return sqrt((double)((m_org.x()-m_end.x())*(m_org.x()-m_end.x()) + (m_org.y()-m_end.y())*(m_org.y()-m_end.y())));
}

void Line::Save2File(ofstream& myfile) const {// save to file
    myfile << 'L' << " " << m_color << " " << m_org.x() << " " << m_org.y() << " "
        << m_end.x() << " " << m_end.y() << endl;
}

//------------------Rectangle methods----------------
void Rectangle::draw(char tabs) const
{
    cout << string(tabs, '\t');
    Point temp1 = m_org;
    Point temp2 = m_org;
    Line l1(temp1, temp2.move(width, 0), m_color);
    temp1 = temp2;
    Line l2(temp2, temp1.move(0, height), m_color);
    temp2 = temp1;
    Line l3(temp1, temp2.move(-width, 0), m_color);
    temp1 = temp2;
    Line l4(temp2, temp1.move(0, -height), m_color);
    Who_am_I(); cout << endl;
    cout << string(tabs, '\t'); l1.draw(1);
    cout << string(tabs, '\t'); l2.draw(1);
    cout << string(tabs, '\t'); l3.draw(1);
    cout << string(tabs, '\t'); l4.draw(1);
}

void Rectangle::Save2File(ofstream& myfile) const {// save to file
    myfile << 'R' << " " << m_color << " " << m_org.x() << " " << m_org.y() << " " << width
        << " " << height << endl;
}

//----------------------Circle methods---------------------------
void Circle::draw(char tabs) const
{
    cout << string(tabs, '\t');
    Who_am_I();
    cout << " Center in " << m_org << " Radius is " << radius << endl;
}

void Circle::Save2File(ofstream& myfile) const {// save to file
    myfile << 'C' << " " << m_color << " " << m_org.x() << " " << m_org.y() << " "
        << radius << endl;
}


//----------------------Picture methods--------------------------
void Picture::insert_shape(Shape* s) // insert a new shape to picture
{
    if (m_count == 0)  {//new picture creating
        m_shapes = new Shape*[1];
        if (!m_shapes)
            cout << "Can't allocate memory!";
    }
    if (m_count > 0){
        Shape** temp = new Shape*[m_count];
        memcpy(temp, m_shapes, sizeof(Shape*)*m_count); //save to temp
        delete m_shapes; //delete old array
        m_shapes = new Shape*[m_count + 1];  //add 1 more place
        if (!m_shapes)
            cout << "Can't allocate memory!";
        memcpy(m_shapes, temp, sizeof(Shape*)*m_count); //return to array
        delete temp; 
    }
    m_shapes[m_count] = s;  // insert the new shape into the last slot in the array
    m_shapes[m_count]->move(m_org); //adjusts the location of the shape
    m_count++;      // increment the number of shapes in picture
}



void Picture::draw(char tabs) const
{
    cout << string(tabs, '\t');
    cout << "------------------ "; 
    Who_am_I();
    cout << " ----------------------" << endl;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m_count; i++)
    {
        m_shapes[i]->draw(tabs + 1);    // draw each shape
    }
    cout << string(tabs, '\t');
    cout << "------------------ End ";
    Who_am_I();
    cout << " ------------------ " << endl;
}

double Picture::Area() const //sum of areas of all shapes in the picture
{
    double area = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; i++)
    {
        area += m_shapes[i]->Area();
    }
    return area;
}


Picture::~Picture()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; i++){
        if (m_shapes[i])
            delete m_shapes[i];
    }
    Who_am_I(); cout << " deleting..." << endl;
    // sometimes (every 5-10 runs) error here. can't reproduce and debug
    if (m_shapes)
        delete m_shapes; 
    // seems like program try to delete already freed memory
}

void Picture::Save2File(ofstream& myfile) const // save to file
{
    myfile << 'P' << " " << m_color << " " << m_org.x() << " " << m_org.y() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; i++)
        m_shapes[i]->Save2File(myfile);
    myfile << 'E' << endl; // end of a picture
}
```

drawing_app.cpp

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW

#include "geometry.h"
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_PICS_IN_PIC 3
#define MAX_SHAPES 5
using namespace std;

void randomizer(Picture*, int); //recursive function
Picture* Load(istream&);
Point GenP(void);
color GenC(void);
int GenLen(void);

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    Picture *main_pic = new Picture(Point(0, 0), GenC());
    ofstream myfile_write("myfile.txt", ios::out);
    if (!myfile_write.is_open())
        cout << "Can't open file!" << endl;
    randomizer(main_pic, MAX_PICS_IN_PIC); //recursive function
    main_pic->Save2File(myfile_write); //save picture to file
    myfile_write.close();
    cout << "       Created Picture:" << endl << endl;
    main_pic->draw(0); //draw the main picture
    cout << "Created: " << main_pic->GetAmPic() << " pictures." << endl; // for debugging
    delete[] main_pic;

    ifstream myfile_read("myfile.txt", ios::in);
    if (!myfile_read.is_open())
        cout << "Can't open file!" << endl;
    Picture* buff_pic = Load(myfile_read);  //load the picture from the file
    cout << endl << endl << "       Loaded Picture:" << endl << endl;
    buff_pic->draw(0);  //display loaded picture
    myfile_read.close();
    delete[] buff_pic;

    cout << "\nLeaks: " << _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() << endl;
    return 0;
}

void randomizer(Picture* pic, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SHAPES; i++){
        Point p1 = GenP(); //m_org of the shape
        color c = GenC(); //roll random color
        _shape shape;
        shape = (_shape)(rand() % 4); //roll random shape
        if (shape == line){
            Point p2 = GenP();
            Line* _line = new Line(p1, p2, c);
            pic->insert_shape(_line);
        }
        if (shape == rectangle){
            Rectangle* _rect = new Rectangle(p1, c, GenLen(), GenLen());
            pic->insert_shape(_rect);
        }
        if (shape == circle){
            Circle* _circ = new Circle(p1, c, GenLen());
            pic->insert_shape(_circ);
        }
        if (shape == picture){
            if (count > 0){
                Picture* inner_pic = new Picture(p1, c);
                count--;
                randomizer(inner_pic, count);
                pic->insert_shape(inner_pic);
            }
            else return;
        }
    }
}

Picture* Load(istream& myfile) {
    int m_color, m_org_x, m_org_y;
    char m_shape;
    myfile >> m_shape >> m_color >> m_org_x >> m_org_y; //read first line
    Picture* pic = new Picture(Point(m_org_x, m_org_y), (color)m_color); //create the main picture
    myfile >> m_shape; //read next line for shape
    while (m_shape != 'E')
    {
        if (m_shape == 'L'){
            int m_end_x, m_end_y;
            myfile >> m_color >> m_org_x >> m_org_y >> m_end_x >> m_end_y;
            Line* _line = new Line(Point(m_org_x, m_org_y), Point(m_end_x, m_end_y), (color)m_color);
            pic->insert_shape(_line);
        }
        if (m_shape == 'C'){
            int radius;
            myfile >> m_color >> m_org_x >> m_org_y >> radius;
            Circle* Circel = new Circle(Point(m_org_x, m_org_y), (color)m_color, radius);
            pic->insert_shape(Circel);
        }
        if (m_shape == 'R') {
            int m_width, m_height;
            myfile >> m_color >> m_org_x >> m_org_y >> m_width >> m_height;
            Rectangle* Rect = new Rectangle(Point(m_org_x, m_org_y), (color)m_color,
                m_width, m_height);
            pic->insert_shape(Rect);
        }
        if (m_shape == 'P') {
            myfile.seekg(-1, ios::cur);
            Picture* inner_pic = Load(myfile);
            pic->insert_shape(inner_pic);
        }
        myfile >> m_shape;
    }
    return pic;
}

Point GenP(){ //roll random point x = 0 to 30, y = 0 to 30
    Point p(rand() % 31, rand() % 31);
    return p;
}

color GenC(){ //generate random color
    return (color)(rand() % 6);
}

int GenLen(){ // generate random length from 1 to 50
    return rand() % 50 + 1;
}
```

Every 5-10 runs I got strange error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5214A9E8 (msvcr120d.dll) in Geometry.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDC1.

Referring me to Destructor of `Picture` class. I can't reproduce this error and can't find the source of this error. Do you have any ideas how I can debug it?

Comment: Why are you using an "m_" prefix on local variables? Most people use that to indicate a member variable.

Comment: `Shape** m_shapes;   //array of pointers to shapes` -- Use containers and smart pointers instead of raw pointers.  Your issue is more than likely mishandling of pointers.

Comment: It takes one line of code to cause undefined behavior: `int main() {Picture p(Picture(Point(0, 0), GenC());}`. Your `m_shapes` is not initialized, yet you attempt to `delete` it in the `Picture` destructor.  Whether that is the actual reason why you now have an issue is another story, but your class is easily broken by the above.

Comment: `void Picture::insert_shape(Shape* s) // insert a new shape to picture` -- Use `std::vector<Shape*>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>>`, and save yourself from having to do all of this work.

Comment: I didn't learn about containers in my course :(
Thank you, PaulMcKenzie, I fixed it by changing the constructor to: 
`Picture(const Point& p1 = 0, color c = White) : Shape(p1, c, picture), m_count(0){ 
  m_shapes = new Shape*[m_count];
  idx++; 
 }`

Comment: We also didn't learn vectors, so I can't use it in my work.

Comment: Debug builds of applications fill various states of memory with special values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values 0xCDCDCDCD is uninitialised memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious error is that it is entirely (and easily) possible to attempt to `delete` an uninitialized `m_shapes` pointer in the `Picture` destructor.

The outline of your code is this:

```
class Picture : public Shape {
private:
    Picture(const Picture&); //CCtor is not accessible from main
protected:
    Shape** m_shapes;   //array of pointers to shapes
    int m_count;        //number of shapes
    static unsigned idx; //number of pictures created for debug
public:
    Picture(const Point& p1 = 0, color c = White) : Shape(p1, c, picture), m_count(0){ idx++; }
    //...
    ~Picture();
};
```

In the `~Picture()` function, you do the following:

```
Picture::~Picture()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; i++){
        if (m_shapes[i])
            delete m_shapes[i];
    }

    if (m_shapes)  // This may not have been initialized!!
        delete m_shapes; 
}
```

In the `Picture()` constructor, you failed to initialize `m_shapes`, thus a simple one line program would be able to invoke the undefined behavior of calling `delete` on an uninitialized pointer.

Example:

```
int main() 
{
    Picture p(Picture(Point(0, 0), GenC()));
} // The `p` destructor will invoke undefined behavior.
```

Therefore the immediate fix is to go back and make sure `m_shapes` is initialized to (at least) a `nullptr` on construction of `Picture`.

---

However the ultimate fix is to start to use `std::vector` and other containers, in addition to using smart pointers such as `std::shared_ptr<Shape>` and/or `std::unique_ptr<Shape>`.  When you do this, functions such as `Picture::insert_shape` become either obsolete, or are simple one-line functions issuing a call to (for example) `std::vector<Shape*>::push_back()`.

For example (using a vector of raw pointers)

```
#include <vector>
class Picture
{
    //...
    std::vector<Shape *> m_shapes;
    void insert_shape(Shape* s);
   //...
};

void Picture::insert_shape(Shape* s) 
{
   m_shapes.push_back(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug the crash in C++ code, let me show you how to use and inspect dumps:

1. Use adplus.exe (get it from Microsoft) and run your app in process monitor mode
2. Download WinDBG (also from Microsoft)
3. Use the following command to create a dump in monitor mode of your process

   ```
   ADPlus -Crash -pmn Geometry.exe -o C:\CrashDumps
   ```
4. Open the crash dump in WinDBG
5. Learn the power of WinDBG

A note: You might need symbols (.pdb) files to be created/loaded in your dump inspection

Comment: My guess on your bug is some pointer arithmetic issues accessing code that is outside the memory address space alloted to your program (which the OS doesn't allow you to do due to security issues)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line.

```
Picture *main_pic = new Picture(Point(0, 0), GenC());
```

You're not giving the size to your Picture pointer and you're deleting it like an array, You must assign a size to your pointer then you also can delete is like this.

```
delete [] main_pic;
```